# Is $X_i$ in the following question uniform $\,k$-wise independent bits?

Tags: uniform-distribution

This is a homework question in the book named *`probability and computing`*.

$13.9$ : suppose we are given m vectors $\overrightarrow v_1,  \overrightarrow v_2 , \cdots, \overrightarrow v_m \in  \{ 0, 1\}^l$  such that any $k$ of the $m$ vectors are linearly independent modulo $2$ . Let $\overrightarrow v_i = (v_i,_1 , v_i,_2 , \cdots, v_i,_l)$. Let $\overrightarrow u$ be chosen uniformly at random from  $\{ 0, 1\}^l$, and let $Xi = \sum_j_=_1^lv_i,_ju_j$ mod $2$, show that the $X_i$ are uniform, $k$-wise independent bits.

Firstly, I doubt that whether $X_i$ is uniform, suppose $l$ assumes $1$, so $X_i = v_i,_1u_1$, and $v_1,_1$ has equal probability $(1/2)$ to be $0$ or $1$, likewise $u_1$.
 $$
        \begin{array}{c|lcr}
          & 1 & 0\\
        \hline
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{array}
$$
the matrix tells us $X_i$ has probabilty $1/4$ to be $1$ and $3/4$ to be $0$, so it's not uniform, so the conclusion in the question is wrong. I want to know whether my analysis is reasonable and then if I am wrong, how to derive the proof? thanks

Answer (score 0):

After several days of trying, I work it out ;-)

Firstly, I should clarify my misunderstanding of this problem, $\overrightarrow v_i$ is not a variable, which is given in the condition , so the conclusion $v_i,_j$ has the probability $1\over2$ to be 0 or 1 is wrong.

Next I will post my solution to this problem

(1) unifom:

how to show that $Xi = \sum_j_=_1^lv_i,_ju_j$ mod 2 is uniform? Firstly, for $\overrightarrow v_i$ is *k-wise indpendent*, so it can not be like this [0...0] (all are zero), otherwise it's contradictory, here we use deffered discisions. suppose $v_i,_j$ is 1, and we reveal any position except j in $\overrightarrow u$, then whether $X_i$ is 0 or 1 is decided by the value of $u_j$, which is unifom between 0 and 1.

(2) k-wise indepent: Here we prove it by induction:

1. consider two vector $\overrightarrow v_1, \overrightarrow v_2$ and $\overrightarrow u_1 , \overrightarrow u_2$ then $X_1 = \sum_j_=_1^lv_1,_ju_1,_j$, $X_2 $ =$\sum_j_=_1^lv_2,_ju_2,_j$.
   X1 = c, X2 = d and  c, d $\in$ {0,1}, we should prove that P(X1 = c $\cap$ X2 = d ) = 1/2.

   we reveal $\overrightarrow u_2$, suppose position m in $\overrightarrow v_1$ is 1, then we also reveal other position in  $\overrightarrow v_1$, this is also known as principle of  deffered dicision, so we can determine X2. And value of X1 is decided by $u_1,_m$ which is uniform between {0,1}. So **P(X1 = c $\cap$ X2 = d | X2 = d) = 1/2**, because of P(X2 = d) = 1/2, **P(X1 = c $\cap$ X2 = d) = 1/4**
2. deduction should prove that P($\cap X_i = a_i$) = $1\over 2^k$, suppose k-1 vectors hold that ,then introduce a new vector $\overrightarrow v_k$, analyse like 1. then it gets proved.
3. (Note : perhaps you will ask that , you don't use the predicate $\overrightarrow v_i$ is k-wise independent. Indeed I take advantage of it, in step 2, suppose we reveal the k-1 vectors, if $\overrightarrow v_i$ is n-wise independent where n < k , then $\overrightarrow v_k$ is determined. However in step 2, $\overrightarrow v_k$ is not determined and we then reveal partial of $\overrightarrow v_k$ except $m$ position is based on the condition.)

end.